# How to implement linear interpolation?

Tags: python, interpolation, linear-interpolation

Say I am given data as follows:

```
x = [1, 2.5, 3.4, 5.8, 6]
y = [2, 4, 5.8, 4.3, 4]
```

I want to design a function that will interpolate linearly between `1` and `2.5`, `2.5` to `3.4`, and so on using Python.

I have tried looking through [this Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial), but I am still unable to get my head around it.

Comment: This is ... not easy. What have you tried?

Comment: -1 as way too general.  you don't understand how to program, or how to do the algorithm in python??

Comment: Well being a new learner I've thrown myself into the deep end so to speak. 

I was thinking of using 'for' or 'if' statements in a algorithm. So between numerous ranges of x.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)

Comment: IMO, being a newbie is not a good excuse for not even trying—in fact it's exactly the opposite (i.e. an excellent reason to do so).

Comment: If you want to only interpolate between 2 points, you can use numpy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Otherwise, Dave's answer below is best.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to write some function `y = interpolate(x_values, y_values, x)`, which will give you the `y` value at some `x`? The basic idea then follows these steps:

1. Find the indices of the values in `x_values` which define an interval containing `x`. For instance, for `x=3` with your example lists, the containing interval would be `[x1,x2]=[2.5,3.4]`, and the indices would be `i1=1`, `i2=2`
2. Calculate the slope on this interval by `(y_values[i2]-y_values[i1])/(x_values[i2]-x_values[i1])` (ie `dy/dx`).
3. The value at `x` is now the value at `x1` plus the slope multiplied by the distance from `x1`.

You will additionally need to decide what happens if `x` is outside the interval of `x_values`, either it's an error, or you could interpolate "backwards", assuming the slope is the same as the first/last interval.

Did this help, or did you need more specific advice?

Answer (score 58):

```
import scipy.interpolate
y_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
print y_interp(5.0)
```

[`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d) does linear interpolation by and can be customized to handle error conditions.

Comment: The question asks how to implement the function, not what library provides it.

Comment: And the answer to such question then - you don't. 
There are wheels you don't reinvent for a very good reason - if you seek first account understanding of them you go to the source, i.e. math book and try them out using best tools you have.
You don't seek a painting lesson in a brush shop.

Answer (score 22):

```py
def interpolate(x1: float, x2: float, y1: float, y2: float, x: float):
    """Perform linear interpolation for x between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) """

    return ((y2 - y1) * x + x2 * y1 - x1 * y2) / (x2 - x1)
```

Comment: What a shame. This is the `lerp` function everyone who searches for wants, in pure Python, even has a docstring—a perfect answer. And I had to scroll to see it.

Answer (score 20):

I thought up a rather elegant solution (IMHO), so I can't resist posting it:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

class Interpolate(object):
    def __init__(self, x_list, y_list):
        if any(y - x <= 0 for x, y in zip(x_list, x_list[1:])):
            raise ValueError("x_list must be in strictly ascending order!")
        x_list = self.x_list = map(float, x_list)
        y_list = self.y_list = map(float, y_list)
        intervals = zip(x_list, x_list[1:], y_list, y_list[1:])
        self.slopes = [(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) for x1, x2, y1, y2 in intervals]

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        i = bisect_left(self.x_list, x) - 1
        return self.y_list[i] + self.slopes[i] * (x - self.x_list[i])
```

I map to `float` so that integer division (python <= 2.7) won't kick in and ruin things if `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` are all integers for some iterval.

In `__getitem__` I'm taking advantage of the fact that self.x_list is sorted in ascending order by using `bisect_left` to (very) quickly find the index of the largest element smaller than `x` in `self.x_list`.

Use the class like this:

```
i = Interpolate([1, 2.5, 3.4, 5.8, 6], [2, 4, 5.8, 4.3, 4])
# Get the interpolated value at x = 4:
y = i[4]
```

I've not dealt with the border conditions at all here, for simplicity. As it is, `i[x]` for `x < 1` will work as if the line from (2.5, 4) to (1, 2) had been extended to minus infinity, while `i[x]` for `x == 1` or `x > 6` will raise an `IndexError`. Better would be to raise an IndexError in all cases, but this is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: I'd find using  `__call__` instead of `__getitem__` to be preferrable in general, its usually an  interpolation *function*.

Comment: Does not work with Python3, as indexing a map is not supported anymore

Comment: inventing a wheel. What's needed is a analogue of C++ std::lerp

Answer (score 10):

Building on Lauritz` answer, here's a version with the following changes

- Updated to python3 (the map was causing problems for me and is unnecessary)
- Fixed behavior at edge values
- Raise exception when x is out of bounds
- Use `__call__` instead of `__getitem__`

```
from bisect import bisect_right

class Interpolate:
    def __init__(self, x_list, y_list):
        if any(y - x <= 0 for x, y in zip(x_list, x_list[1:])):
            raise ValueError("x_list must be in strictly ascending order!")
        self.x_list = x_list
        self.y_list = y_list
        intervals = zip(x_list, x_list[1:], y_list, y_list[1:])
        self.slopes = [(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) for x1, x2, y1, y2 in intervals]

    def __call__(self, x):
        if not (self.x_list[0] <= x <= self.x_list[-1]):
            raise ValueError("x out of bounds!")
        if x == self.x_list[-1]:
            return self.y_list[-1]
        i = bisect_right(self.x_list, x) - 1
        return self.y_list[i] + self.slopes[i] * (x - self.x_list[i])
```

Example usage:

```
>>> interp = Interpolate([1, 2.5, 3.4, 5.8, 6], [2, 4, 5.8, 4.3, 4])
>>> interp(4)
5.425
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of extrapolating off the ends, you could return the extents of the `y_list`. Most of the time your application is well behaved, and the `Interpolate[x]` will be in the `x_list`. The (presumably) linear affects of extrapolating off the ends may mislead you to believe that your data is well behaved.

- Returning a non-linear result (bounded by the contents of `x_list` and `y_list`) your program's behavior may alert you to an issue for values greatly outside `x_list`. (Linear behavior goes bananas when given non-linear inputs!)
- Returning the extents of the `y_list` for `Interpolate[x]` outside of `x_list` also means you know the range of your output value. If you extrapolate based on `x` much, much less than `x_list[0]` or `x` much, much greater than `x_list[-1]`, your return result could be outside of the range of values you expected.

  ```
  def __getitem__(self, x):
      if x <= self.x_list[0]:
          return self.y_list[0]
      elif x >= self.x_list[-1]:
          return self.y_list[-1]
      else:
          i = bisect_left(self.x_list, x) - 1
          return self.y_list[i] + self.slopes[i] * (x - self.x_list[i])
  ```

Comment: I'd find using  `__call__` instead of `__getitem__` to be preferrable in general, its usually an  interpolation *function*.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution did not work in Python 2.7. There was an error while checking for the order of the x elements. I had to change to code to this to get it to work:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
class Interpolate(object):
    def __init__(self, x_list, y_list):
        if any([y - x <= 0 for x, y in zip(x_list, x_list[1:])]):
            raise ValueError("x_list must be in strictly ascending order!")
        x_list = self.x_list = map(float, x_list)
        y_list = self.y_list = map(float, y_list)
        intervals = zip(x_list, x_list[1:], y_list, y_list[1:])
        self.slopes = [(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) for x1, x2, y1, y2 in intervals]
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        i = bisect_left(self.x_list, x) - 1
        return self.y_list[i] + self.slopes[i] * (x - self.x_list[i])
```

Comment: I get an error.... TypeError 'Interpolate' object is not callable ??  What is the solution?