# Interpolation of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, interpolation

I do have a pandas DataFrame (size = 34,19) which I want to use as a lookup table.

But the values I want to look up are "between" the values in the dataframe

For example:

```
      0.1      0.2      0.3     0.4    0.5
0.1   4.01  31.86   68.01   103.93  139.2
0.2  24.07  57.49   91.37   125.21  158.57
0.3  44.35  76.4    108.97  141.57  173.78
0.4  59.66  91.02   122.8   154.62  186.13
0.5  87.15  117.9   148.86  179.83  210.48
0.6  106.92 137.41  168.26  198.99  229.06
0.7  121.73 152.48  183.4   213.88  243.33
```

I know want to look up the value for x = 5.5 y = 1.004, so the answer should be around 114.

I tried it with different methods from scipy but the values I get are always way off.
Last method I used was :`inter = interpolate.interpn([np.array(np.arange(34)), np.array(np.arange(19))], np_matrix, [x_value, y_value],)`
I even get wrong values for points in the grid which do exist.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or recommend an easy solution for the task?

---

**EDIT:**

An additional problem is:
My raw data, from an .xlsx file, look like:

```
      0.1      0.2      0.3     0.4    0.5
0.1   4.01  31.86   68.01   103.93  139.2
0.2  24.07  57.49   91.37   125.21  158.57
0.3  44.35  76.4    108.97  141.57  173.78
0.4  59.66  91.02   122.8   154.62  186.13
0.5  87.15  117.9   148.86  179.83  210.48
0.6  106.92 137.41  168.26  198.99  229.06
0.7  121.73 152.48  183.4   213.88  243.33
```

But pandas adds an Index column:

```
               0.1      0.2      0.3     0.4    0.5
0     0.1     4.01    31.86    68.01    103.93  139.2
1     0.2    24.07    57.49    91.37    125.21  158.57
2     0.3    44.35    76.4    108.97    141.57  173.78
3     0.4    59.66    91.02   122.8     154.62  186.13
4     0.8    87.15   117.9    148.86    179.83  210.48
5     1.0   106.92   137.41   168.26    198.99  229.06
6     1.7   121.73   152.48   183.4     213.88  243.33
```

So if I want to access x = 0.4 y = 0.15 I have to input x = 3, y = 0.15.

Data are read with:

```
model_references = pd.ExcelFile(model_references_path)
Matrix = model_references.parse('Model_References')
n = Matrix.stack().reset_index().values
out = interpolate.griddata(n[:,0:2], n[:,2], (Stroke, Current), method='cubic')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reshape data to 3 columns with `stack` - first column for `index`, second for columns and last for values, last get values by [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

a = 5.5
b = 1.004

n = df.stack().reset_index().values    
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/8662243
out = griddata(n[:,0:2], n[:,2], [(a, b)], method='linear')
print (out)
[104.563]
```

**Detail**:

```
n = df.stack().reset_index().values
print (n)
[[  1.     1.     4.01]
 [  1.     2.    31.86]
 [  1.     3.    68.01]
 [  1.     4.   103.93]
 [  1.     5.   139.2 ]
 [  2.     1.    24.07]
 [  2.     2.    57.49]
 [  2.     3.    91.37]
 [  2.     4.   125.21]
 [  2.     5.   158.57]
 [  3.     1.    44.35]
 [  3.     2.    76.4 ]
 [  3.     3.   108.97]
 [  3.     4.   141.57]
 [  3.     5.   173.78]
 [  4.     1.    59.66]
 [  4.     2.    91.02]
 [  4.     3.   122.8 ]
 [  4.     4.   154.62]
 [  4.     5.   186.13]
 [  5.     1.    87.15]
 [  5.     2.   117.9 ]
 [  5.     3.   148.86]
 [  5.     4.   179.83]
 [  5.     5.   210.48]
 [  5.     1.   106.92]
 [  5.     2.   137.41]
 [  5.     3.   168.26]
 [  5.     4.   198.99]
 [  5.     5.   229.06]
 [  6.     1.   121.73]
 [  6.     2.   152.48]
 [  6.     3.   183.4 ]
 [  6.     4.   213.88]
 [  6.     5.   243.33]]
```

Comment: Thank you thats an easy solution, but I now have to problem that I the dataframe adds an additional Index column (0-33). I do want that only the raw data is the first column

Comment: @GittingGud - You get different output like my edited data?

Comment: No if I use the example I provided in the question I get the same output as you (thanks to your solution) but the dataframe I use gets imported from a .xlsx and pandas adds an Index column going 0,1,2, ..., 33. So the dataframe's first column isn't my real first column which means I cannot access it properly with the "a" value. I will edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: @GittingGud - What is your code for read excel? Maybe need `df = df.read_excel(file, index_col=[0])`

Comment: `df = pandas.ExcelFile(filepath)` | `df = pandas.ExcelFile(filepath, index_col=[0])` is and unexpected argument

Comment: @GittingGud - if change `ExcelFile` to `read_excel` it working?

Comment: @GittingGud - yes, is possible add few rows of code after `df = pandas.ExcelFile` ?

Comment: added at the bottom of the question

Comment: @GittingGud - Thank you, need `Matrix = model_references.parse('Model_References', index_col=0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193886/discussion-between-jezrael-and-gittinggud).

Answer (score 1):

Try `interp2d` from scipy.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
z = [[4.01, 31.86, 68.01, 103.93, 139.2],
[24.07, 57.49, 91.37, 125.21, 158.57],
[44.35, 76.4, 108.97, 141.57, 173.78],
[59.66, 91.02, 122.8, 154.62, 186.13],
[87.15, 117.9, 148.86, 179.83, 210.48],
[106.92, 137.41, 168.26, 198.99, 229.06],
[121.73, 152.48, 183.4, 213.88, 243.33]]
z = np.array(z).T

f = interp2d(x, y, z)
f(x = 5.5, y = 1.004) # returns 97.15748
```

Try to change method's `kind` argument in order to experiment with return value.