# Bilinear interpolation from structured grid to unstructured grid (arbitrary points)

Tags: python, gis, interpolation, netcdf, cdo-climate

I need to interpolate bilinearly some air data of a hdf4/netcdf4/hdf5 file from a 240x240 structured grid on an arbitrary collection of coordinates. I have no idea on how to do this. I have tried using **pyresample** but that needs an AreaDefinition of target grid which is not possible in my case of unstructured target data (arbitrary points). Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyresample
from   netCDF4 import Dataset

air_file  = Dataset('air.hdf', mode='r')
air_data  = air_file.variables['air_2m' ][:].flatten()
air_lon   = air_file.variables['air_lon'][:].flatten()
air_lat   = air_file.variables['air_lat'][:].flatten()
air_data  = air_data.reshape(240,240)
air_lon   = air_lon. reshape(240,240) # grid size is 240x240
air_lat   = air_lat. reshape(240,240)

tar_lon   = 100 * np.random.random((100,1)) # random points 
tar_lat   = 100 * np.random.random((100,1)) # random points

source_def = pyresample.geometry.SwathDefinition(lons=air_lon, lats=air_lat)
target_def = pyresample.geometry.SwathDefinition(lons=tar_lon, lats=tar_lat)
result     = pyresample.bilinear.resample_bilinear(gmt_1500, source_def, target_def, radius=50e3, neighbours=32, nprocs=1, fill_value=None, reduce_data=True, segments=None, epsilon=0)
```

I am getting the following error (which is understood as it needs an AreaDefinition for target):

```
AttributeError: 'SwathDefinition' object has no attribute 'proj_str'
```

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: It's a little more involved, but fitting a Gaussian process to your data with an RBF kernel will let you extrapolate to any other points, regularly-sampled or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the pyresample package, but for bilinear interpolation in python I suggest referring to this earlier stackexchange thread which gives a number of useful examples:

[How to perform bilinear interpolation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661537/how-to-perform-bilinear-interpolation-in-python)

p.s: By the way, if anyone wants to perform this task from the command line, you can also extract a set of points using bilinear interpolation with cdo too

```
# some bash loop over a pairs of x and y
cdo remapbil,lon=${x}/lat=${x} in.nc mypoint_${x}_${y}.nc
```