# RegularGridInterpolator excruciatingly slow compared to interp2d

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, deprecation-warning, linear-interpolation

Consider the following code example:

```
# %%
import numpy
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d, RegularGridInterpolator

x = numpy.arange(9000)
y = numpy.arange(9000)
z = numpy.random.randint(-1000, high=1000, size=(9000, 9000))
f = interp2d(x, y, z, kind='linear', copy=False)

f2 = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y), z, "linear")

mx, my = np.meshgrid(x, y)
M = np.stack([mx, my], axis=-1)

# %%
%timeit f(x, y)

# %%
%timeit f2(M)
```

It sets up some example interpolators using `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` and `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator`. The output of the two cells above is

> 1.09 s ± 4.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

and

> 10 s ± 17.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

respectively.

The `RegularGridInterpolator` is about 10 times slower than the `interp2d`. The problem is that `interp2d` has been [marked as deprecated in scipy 1.10.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy-interpolate-interp2d). And new code should use `RegularGridInterpolator`. This seems a bit strange to me since it would be such a bad replacement. Is there maybe a problem in my code example above? How can I speed this interpolation process up?

Comment: you could use [RectBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html)?

Comment: Good question!
I can confirm that performance of RegularGridInterpolator is approx 10x slower than inerp2d. *and* its api is more difficult to use for simple 2d problems with measured points.

Comment: ... update - I've tried using RegularGridInterpolator on another example (from [here](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/examples/scipyinterpolateinterp2d/) . It uses cubic interpolation. The difference is dramatic - 175us for interp2d vs 1.2 **seconds** for the new code. I guess we'll just have to stick with scipy 1.10 for now and silence the warnings... a bit sad about this.

Comment: reported as a bug on [github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/18010)

Comment: I experience the same!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with your code, it's probably a bug in scipy.
I've reported it on [github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/18010)

Comment: Commenting here for visibility. It is a known performance regression and we are actively working on it. The new interface was needed in term of maintainability moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from SciPy 1.13, RGI tensor-product spline modes (slinear, cubic and quintic) should be much faster. While 1.13 is not released yet, you can use scipy nightly builds.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I already can start using this improved version of the RegularGridInterpolator?

Comment: Install a nightly build or a 1.13rc1 release. The usage is unchanged.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.13.0rc1/

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles on this:

Turns out that calculating bilinear interpolation manually is about ***10x faster*** than scipy's `RegularGridInterpolator`. When I say "manually", I mean:

1. Start with the same `points` (let's say `x_vals` with length N and `y_vals` with length M) and `values` (let's say `z_grid` with shape NxM) arrays you'd pass to `RegularGridInterpolator`.
2. Given your desired coordinates (let's say `x,y`), find indices of the four nearest points using `np.searchsorted()` (this works on its own if `x_vals`/`y_vals` is *increasing* -- if either is *decreasing*, see code below).
3. Calculate bilinear interpolation using a standard formula, I use [Raymond Hettinger's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8662355/22122546).

Here's a slightly modified excerpt from my own implementation:

```py
# since `x_vals` and `y_vals` are decreasing rather than increasing, we do some trickery on top of `np.searchsorted()` to get the desired indices.
i_x = x_vals.shape[0] - np.searchsorted(np.flip(x_vals), x)
i_y = y_vals.shape[0] - np.searchsorted(np.flip(y_vals), y)

points = (
    (
        x_vals[i_x - 1],
        y_vals[i_y - 1],
        z_grid[i_x - 1, i_y - 1]
    ),
    (
        x_vals[i_x],
        y_vals[i_y - 1],
        z_grid[i_x, i_y - 1]
    ),
    (
        x_vals[i_x - 1],
        y_vals[i_y],
        z_grid[i_x - 1, i_y]
    ),
    (
        x_vals[i_x],
        y_vals[i_y],
        z_grid[i_x, i_y]
    )
)

'''here's an option with list comprehension
points = [
    (
        x_vals[i_x-1+i],
        y_vals[i_y-1+j],
        z_grid[i_x-1+i, i_y-1+j]
    )
    for i, j in [(i, j) for i in range(2) for j in range(2)]
]
'''

return bilinear_interpolation(x, y, points) # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8662355/22122546
```

Like I said before, this is about 10 times faster than `RegularGridInterpolator` from my own testing. I have no idea why scipy doesn't provide a warning about this in documentation, I've wasted hours on this lol. But at least there's a clean solution :>

Take care!