# Why does this linear interpolation no longer work in Python > 2.7?

Tags: python, interpolation

I've found this script for linear interpolation in Python on Stack Overflow. It works perfectly well in Python 2.7, but fails in newer versions.

Here is the code:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

class Interpolate(object):
    def __init__(self, x_list, y_list):
        if any(y - x <= 0 for x, y in zip(x_list, x_list[1:])):
            raise ValueError("x_list must be in strictly ascending order!")
        x_list = self.x_list = map(float, x_list)
        y_list = self.y_list = map(float, y_list)
        intervals = zip(x_list, x_list[1:], y_list, y_list[1:])
        self.slopes = [(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) for x1, x2, y1, y2 in intervals]

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        i = bisect_left(self.x_list, x) - 1
        return self.y_list[i] + self.slopes[i] * (x - self.x_list[i])

i = Interpolate ([0,2,3], [9,5,8])
y = i[1]
```

This is the error I’m getting:

```
TypeError: 'Interpolate' object does not support indexing.
```

What has been changed that means the code won’t work anymore?

Comment: What version of Python are you running with? I get a slightly different error with Python 3.4.1: on line `intervals = zip(x_list, x_list[1:], y_list, y_list[1:])`, I have `TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`. // Oh wait, I see.

Comment: I'm running Python 2.7.9. Checking it on 3.4.3 right now.

Comment: lattest time I had to do an interpolation, I used the library SciPy, which has nicely already made the function for me (aimed at scientists and numerical computing so it is bug free and efficient). https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/interpolate.html

Comment: Where did you find that code?

Comment: I cannot repeat the exact error code, please edit the question so that it contains the exact error and code that reproduces the error in question

Comment: I've already posted the exact error, I dont not get any other...

Comment: The SciPy is not always available

Comment: You should include a reference to the question or author when you post code written by someone else: in this case [the original code by Lauritz V. Thaulow is an answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343697/linear-interpolation-python)

Answer (score 3):

This is a change to the `map()` function in Python 3. In Python 2.x, it would return a list, but now it returns an iterator.

Quoting from [*What’s New in Python 3*](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> `map()` and `filter()` return iterators. If you really need a list, a quick fix is e.g. `list(map(...))`, but a better fix is often to use a list comprehension (especially when the original code uses lambda), or rewriting the code so it doesn’t need a list at all. Particularly tricky is `map()` invoked for the side effects of the function; the correct transformation is to use a regular for loop (since creating a list would just be wasteful).

So the problem is occurring on these two lines:

```
x_list = self.x_list = map(float, x_list)
y_list = self.y_list = map(float, y_list)
intervals = zip(x_list, x_list[1:], y_list, y_list[1:])
```

When you try to subscript `x_list` and `y_list` when creating `intervals` (this is the `[1:]` slice), it fails because you can’t subscript an iterator.

One fix is to replace the `x_list` and `y_list` lines with these list comprehensions:

```
x_list = self.x_list = [float(x) for x in x_list]
y_list = self.y_list = [float(y) for y in y_list]
```

Not only will this allow subscripting (and so the code works as you expect), but this will still work on old versions of Python and I think it’s clearer what’s going on.

Comment: An alternative fix is to explicitly transform the maps to lists; `list(map(float, x_list))`. Readability arguments could be made for either case.

Comment: I've tried using the fix like you told on both 2.7.9 and 3.4.3, alexwlchan, but it didnt help. It still works on 2.7 tho

Comment: @FilthyL Hmm. I’m using 2.7.6 and 3.4.1, and the code works fine. Could you post the entire traceback of the error? It’s possible I’m looking in the wrong place.

Comment: File "<pyshell#9>", line 1 in <module>
  y=i[1]
TypeError: 'Interpolate' object does not support indexing

Comment: Looks like the pc is the problem, checked it on another one, works! Thanks a lot !