# Write my own Interpolate function Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation, python-3.6

I am using this script to get the interpolation values from the excel. It is working fine and giving fine results

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import numpy as np

def estimateMonthlySales(domainId,categoryId,salesRank):

    df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheetname='units')
    df = df.set_index('index')

    indexRef = str(domainId)+'_'+str(categoryId)
    startCol = 7

    array_x1 = df.loc[indexRef,:].index
    array_y1 = df.loc[indexRef,:].values

    array_x = []
    for i in range(startCol,len(array_x1)):
        array_x.append(int(array_x1[i]))

    array_y = []
    for i in range(startCol,len(array_y1)):
        try:
            j = int(array_y1[i])
        except:
            pass
        array_y.append(j)

    #print(array_x)
    #print(array_y)

    return(int(np.interp(salesRank, array_x, array_y)*0.98))


print(estimateMonthlySales(2,468292,600))
```

I am using numpy interp function. But i want to write my own interpolate function to get the similar results for my dataset as provided by numpy interpolation functoin. How can i write my own interpolation function without use of numpy and pandas.?

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Does this question/answer does not help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343697/linear-interpolation-python

Comment: The real question is why you want to _not_ use numpy, and will you get rid of the whole deal of pandas manipulations too? Wanting to leave numpy and keeping pandas is...surprising.

Comment: I always have to install these two libraries and on my server i don't want to install these extra libraries. That is why i want my own interpolation.

Comment: @Guto I tried to see that thread but it could not help me in any way.

Comment: Then you should update your question with what you tried as interpolation code and what went wrong. The ABC of interpolation(ideas and even bit of code) are there.